# Getting fatal error when Python C API is called from Go

Tags: go, ffi, cpython

From main.go, I have to call a module(testA) which has dependency on Python run time.
The module 'testA' is a wrapper to wrap the C code into a Python module and this goes thru python interpreter.
Was able to compile the testA module and generate .o files.

I tried to run main.go and encountered following error

```
/usr/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp: fatal error: patchlevel.h: No such file or directory
 #include <patchlevel.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

main.go

```
package main
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall   
#include "../ccode/testA.h"
*/
import "C"
```

Did the foll. installation and still encountered error.

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

The **patchlevel.h** are in different folders

```
/usr/include/python3.6
/usr/include/python2.7
```

I am new to Go world and did my best to find some method to solve this issue.
I need to call the functions from the existing testA in Go.

What is causing this issue?

Comment: 1) Never ever use `go run`; at least until «I am new to Go» is fully resolved  2) You cannot call into some "abstract Python"—only to that one which you actually intend to use. So use the include directory maching the version of Python you intend to actually call—that one which will be (dynamically) linked with the resulting Go executable. If you're not really sure which one it is, I'd try that one matching what's reported by `python --version`

Comment: @kostix, the python version is Python 3.6.9
Yes due to different Python version (2.7,3.6m,3.6,3.7,3.7m) I am lost. $ which python
gives  /usr/bin/python
and $ which python3 gives /usr/bin/python3

Comment: Python 2 and 3 are so much different, programs wtirrent for then are not compatible (in either direction), and that's why these packages are usually made co-installable. Still, you need to work your exact requirements through: consider reaching whoever is responsible for that "TestA module" (whatever that means) and ask them. If you're not sure, just try _ether:_ say, try with 2.x and see what happens; if it fails, try with 3.x.

Comment: @kostix, I checked with the team and they are using Python3.7 to build the testA module. 
how to use the include dir in the Go file ie main.go ? 
If possible can I get an example on how to declaration the include dir in the main.go file?
(Most of the header files under testA folder uses #include <boost/python/ )

Comment: Read [the doc on `cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) in its entirety, please; it really has the answers.